# Login to facebook in android using REST API

Tags: java, android, facebook, httpclient

I develop facebook application in android
i want to log in to facebook via HTTPClient , teh user give me username and password and then i connect to facebook.com/login

i want to make like this code

[Facebook: Getting Incorrect Signature (104) when Getting Session Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409220/facebook-getting-incorrect-signature-104-when-getting-session-key/1795229#1795229)

but in android, i tried to do that but when i get the session, a XML contain invalid parameter returned

can any one help me?

Answer (score 4):

Facebook released an official SDK for Android applications. See [this post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385) on their developers blog.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try implementing the Android Facebook:Connect Library:
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Android

It's not official - but it seems fairly stable for most practical uses (allowing connecting and FQL queries, etc.)

Comment: Yes i know this library and i try it but its unofficial library, and limited and it use mobile browser to log in.

my target is log in without using the browser like the example above in c

anyway thanks for ur replay and interest